# Simple NSTimer implementation issue

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have just started to learn swift 2 and I am testing a few things in an Xcode 'playground'. When a create an instance of the 'pyx' (below) I am not seeing the console output I would expect. I am sure I have made a silly mistake but after staring at it for a while I cannot figure it out.

```
class zxy {

    var gameTimer = NSTimer()
    var counter = 0


    init() {
            gameTimer = NSTimer (timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: "Run:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    func Run(timer : NSTimer) {

        while(counter < 10){
            print(counter)
            counter++
        }

        timer.invalidate()
    }

}
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your code. As @glenstorey points out in his answer, you need to call the method `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`, not the init method you're calling.

### EDIT:

As @DanBeauleu says in his comment to my answer, the call would look like this in Swift:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
  1, 
  target: self, 
  selector: "Run:", 
  userInfo: nil, 
  repeats: true)
```

The second problem is your Run method.

You don't want a while loop. That will repeat 10 times in a tiny fraction of a second the first time the timer fires, then invalidate the timer.

Your timer method needs to be changed like this:

```
func Run(timer : NSTimer) 
{

  if counter < 10
  {
    print(counter)
    counter++
  }
  else
  {
    timer.invalidate()
  }
}
```

(BTW, by strong convention, method/function names should start with a lower-case letter, so your `Run` function should be named `run` instead.)

Comment: +1 . @hcp, if you need the syntax from glenstorey's answer it's this: *gameTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "Run:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)*

Answer (score 3):

You've created a NSTimer object, but that doesn't start the timer - just gets it ready to go. Use [scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:) to create and start the timer.